# New Eclipse Luna for PHP install gives 404 error

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-luna

I have a new install of Eclipse Luna for PHP on Windows 7.

I have created a new PHP project with one PHP file (index.php) with some simple Hello World code.

When I try to Run or Debug I just get an http 404 error generated by Windows IIS.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure IIS to work with PHP or install for example WAMP.

Next you should configure default php web server configuration under PHP/Servers